# Can I tell if my USB flash drive has been plugged into other computers?

Tags: usb-drive

Can I tell if my USB flash drive has been plugged into other devices?

Answer (score 3):

Unless your USB drive has some special features for this (I'm not aware of any drives doing so), there is an easy answer: you can't know whether it was connected to another computer, unless the operating system wrote to it. For example, Mac OS X likes to write some meta information for Finder, their file system explorer, to any disks it gets hold of.

There are special forensic tools and hardware solutions to fully prevent this, though; and simply read-only mounting the drive also will not leave any traces (eg. using Linux).